# why does pepper's tablet stop playing videos?

Tags: pepper

I have created a sample project in choreograph which is responsible for playing a video on pepper's tablet, it works nicely in choreograph. now i packaged and uploaded it on the robot and called this behavior (by albehaviormanger) in my python code as following:

```
behaviormanager = session.service("ALBehaviorManager")
if (behaviormanager.isBehaviorRunning(choregraph_Code)):
    behaviormanager.stopBehavior(choregraph_Code)

behaviormanager.runBehavior(choregraph_Code)
```

It works but sometimes the video stopped suddenly, in every single run in a different moment! so whats the problem with it?

also I tried to play videos from net by:

```
tabletService.enableWifi()
tabletService.loadUrl(url)
tabletService.showWebview()
```

but after some time it stops too

so does any one know what's a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem here is that Autonomous Life is resetting the tablet. And *that* happens because Autonomous Life doesn't know that your behavior is running.

Autonomous Life has the concept of "focused activity"; of which there can only be one at a time (lower priority activities will not be started, and when a higher activity priority is started, the lower priority one will be stopped). Between activities, Autonomous Life resets the tablet, but won't do so inside an activity.

So instead of doing `ALBehaviorManager.runBehavior`, you should use `ALAutonomousLife.switchFocus` (with the same behavior path as a parameter), and AutonomousLife won't reset your tablet.

(Not all behaviors are intended to be activities; some activities have sub-behaviors, and some behaviors may be expected to be running quietly in the background without getting the focus - that's not a good practice, but sometimes happens)

Comment: Thank you so much @Emile for your response, actually i need to play 6 different videos (so six different choregraphe prj) and i used a for loop (i=0 to 5) each time one video would be played. now if a video starts to play then it would be played without stop but in i==2 .. i==3 and so on any video doesn't play! it seems i have to reset something! but i don't know what exactly!